# How to get/set the IP of a hosted network

Tags: c#, netsh, hotspot

I created a virtual WiFi hotspot by the following code, I now need to get its IP address but I actually don't know its network interface's name (as no constant name, 'Local Connection *16' maybe).

The goal is to know its IP address so setting the hosted network's IP shall be one of solutions...but it is preferred that no manual works are involved.

This problem really stuck me......Please help ;(

```
private void Hotspot(string ssid, string key,bool status)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    if (process != null)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + ssid + " key=" + key);
            print ("cmd: "+"netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + ssid + " key=" + key);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan start hostednetwork");
            print ("cmd: " + "netsh wlan start hostednetwork");
            process.StandardInput.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan stop hostednetwork");
            print ("cmd: " + "netsh wlan stop hostednetwork");
            process.StandardInput.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found 2 things might be helpful: 
1) the hosting address value looks like hooked in "regedit.exe", under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\EapolKeyIpAddress value of "LocalAddress" but seems not easy to retrieve it...
2) as using netsh, a Microsoft powered tool, the description of network connection should be the same (**not proved**) written as "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter"
please advice could those be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This solution involves an assumption: the virtual hotspot address using command `netsh wlan` will reference the registry key `LocalAddress` in `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\EapolKeyIpAddress`.

Yet I won't mark it as an answer because it has uncertainty. Discussions or comments are all welcome.

```
private string GetVirtualHotspotIPAddress () {
    using (RegistryKey wlanKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\WlanSvc\\Parameters\\EapolKeyIpAddress")) {
        if (wlanKey != null) {
            object keyValue = wlanKey.GetValue ("LocalAddress");
            if (keyValue != null) {
                return keyValue.ToString ();
            } else {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError ("KEY 'LocalAddress' NOT FOUND");
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError ("No WLANSVC KEY FOUND");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```